# Yii- a record can't be updated from a function called from beforesave() , if i return false from before save

Tags: php, yii

While saving a user i am updating the state of a record in my preference table from beforesave() of user table by calling a licensingObject() method of my SbLicensingbehavior. 
Now if I return true from the beforsave() function then preference table record gets updated.
If I return false then the preference table record is not updated in data base.

user model code:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return array(
        'behaviour_model_download' => array(
            'class' => 'application.components.SbLicensingBehavior'
        )
    );
}
public function beforeSave()
{
    $error = $this->licensingObject('user_count','save');
    if($error){
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Licensing behavior code:

```
<?php
```

class SbLicensingBehavior extends CBehavior
{

```
/**
 * This function will receive the variable as parameter who's current state need to be
 * incremented or decremented based on operation parameter.
 * value send as parameter will be used as amount by which we need to increment our
 * current state variable, it will be usefull incase like we have a limitation on size
 * of a repo.     
 */

public function updateCurrentState($variable,$operation,$value = null)
{
    $preferenceMode = Preference::model()->findByAttributes(array(
        'variable' => $variable,
        'type' => 'system_limit',
    ));
    if(!$preferenceMode){
        return 'not found';
    }
    $currentStateVariable = "current_state_".$variable;

    $currentStatePreferenceModel = Preference::model()->findByAttributes(array(
        'variable' => $currentStateVariable,  
        'type' => 'system_limit'
    ));

    if ($operation == 'save'){
        $currentStatePreferenceModel->value += ($value == null?1:$value);
        if($preferenceMode->value < $currentStatePreferenceModel->value){
            $error = $this->updateFlagState($variable,1);
            return $error;
        }

    }

    if(!$currentStatePreferenceModel->save()){
        return 'Licensing variable can not be updated';
    }
    return $error;
}

/**
 * This function updates the notification variable value.
 */
public function updateFlagState($variable,$value)
{
    $prefrenceNotificationModel = Preference::model()->findByAttributes(array(
        'variable' => 'notification_'.$variable,  
        'type' => 'system_limit'
    ));
    if(!$prefrenceNotificationModel){
        return 'Licensing variable can not be updated'; 
    }
    $prefrenceNotificationModel->value = $value;
    $prefrenceNotificationModel->updated = time();
    if(!$prefrenceNotificationModel->save()) {
        return 'Licensing variable can not be updated';
    }
    return 'done';
}

public function licensingObject($variable,$operation=null,$value=null)
{
    switch ($variable) {
        case "user_count":

                $error = $this->updateCurrentState($variable,$operation,$value);
                return $error;
                if($error == 'done'){
                    return "user count has exceded the licensing limit, user can not be created";       
                }
                break;
            default:
        }
}
```

}

I am not getting what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Doesn't it because it is a designed behavior for the beforeSave() method: @return boolean whether the saving should be executed. Defaults to true.

Comment: I have tried to use the behavior function directly from the controller before saving i.e. before $userModel->save() is called.Same thing happens.if an error is thrown and we return then preference model is not updated. but if i don't return then preference model is updated.